# Notification of Blender Updates

Tags: modeling, python, rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine

Is there a way to get an email notification when there's a Blender update? Or is there an automatic part of Blender that tells you if there's an update?

Comment: Blender itself doesn't inform of new updates, and it doesn't automatically update.  There are mailing lists, twitter accounts, and chats that post update availability announcements, but they all contain other information as well.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52061/should-i-update-blender

Comment: Don't know why this is getting downvoted, this would be a nice thing to have and there are youtube channels that you can subscribe to and turn notifications of that make videos when there's a new Blender update.

Answer (score 3):

You can subscribe to [BF-commiters](http://lists.blender.org/mailman/listinfo/bf-committers) to get information about release cycle and get emails like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using Blender through Steam will do large updates automatically, and you can also use it for alpha/beta releases if you do a bit of digging. It's fantastic for version control. Theres a few reports of people losing their settings in the reviews, but I haven't experienced it personally since using it as of 2.93.

Answer (score 0):

Blender is also available on Microsoft Store and is very highly reviewed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can probably set up automated emails using services like [IFTT](https://ifttt.com/email) to email you on an event, such as a tweet from the BF account mentioning a new release.

You can also use Dotbow's Blender Launcher to notify, download and manage your Blender installations.
[GitHub - DotBow/Blender-Launcher: Standalone client for managing official builds of Blender 3D](https://github.com/DotBow/Blender-Launcher)